Adding permissions with Set-Acl in Powershell removes all inherited permissions on shares
When I try to add a permission using Set-Acl on a share where the share itself has inherited permissions, all inherited permissions are removed. Consider the following setup:
Physical Path                Shared as
C:\File System\TopFolder     \\Server\TopFolder

If I add permissions on C:\File System with inheritance and propagation, those permissions show up on the share \\Server\TopFolder. This is expected. If I use Get-Acl and Set-Acl to modify Access Rules on \\Server\TopFolder, or even when running Get/Set without actually doing anything, then all inherited permissions on that share are removed. Here's an example:
PS C:\> $FileSystemAcl = Get-Acl -Path "C:\File System"

PS C:\> $FileSystemAcl.Access | Select-Object IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,IsInherited

IdentityReference                 FileSystemRights IsInherited
-----------------                 ---------------- -----------
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                    FullControl        True
BUILTIN\Administrators                 FullControl        True
BUILTIN\Users          ReadAndExecute, Synchronize        True
BUILTIN\Users                           AppendData        True
BUILTIN\Users                          CreateFiles        True
CREATOR OWNER                            268435456        True



PS C:\> $ShareAcl = Get-Acl -Path "\\Server\TopFolder"

PS C:\> $ShareAcl.Access | Select-Object IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,IsInherited

IdentityReference                   FileSystemRights IsInherited
-----------------                   ---------------- -----------
DOMAIN\Domain Admins                     FullControl       False
DOMAIN\IT Services                       FullControl       False
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                      FullControl        True
BUILTIN\Administrators                   FullControl        True
BUILTIN\Users            ReadAndExecute, Synchronize        True
BUILTIN\Users                             AppendData        True
BUILTIN\Users                            CreateFiles        True
CREATOR OWNER                              268435456        True


PS C:\> Set-Acl -Path "\\Server\TopFolder" -AclObject $ShareAcl

PS C:\> $ShareAcl = Get-Acl -Path "\\Server\TopFolder"

PS C:\> $ShareAcl.Access | Select-Object IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,IsInherited

IdentityReference           FileSystemRights IsInherited
-----------------           ---------------- -----------
DOMAIN\administrator     Modify, Synchronize       False
DOMAIN\Domain Admins             FullControl       False
DOMAIN\IT Services               FullControl       False

As you can see, the explicit permissions remain but all inherited permissions are removed. I've confirmed that this only happens when you run Set-Acl on the share itself. Notable things I tried:

Using $ShareAcl.SetAccessRuleProtection($false,$true) to make sure it's not the handling of existing permissions that is the issue does not change anything.
Using Get-Item with .GetAccessControl() and .SetAccessControl() gives me the same behaviour.
This only happens when you run it against the share UNC path. If you run this against the physical path the behaviour is not there. As in: just running Get/Set for \\Server\TopFolder removes the inherited permissions, but running Get/Set against C:\File System\TopFolder does not remove the inherited permissions.

For any subfolder or file that is not directly shared, this is not an issue. What could the reason for this only occurring on shares where the shared folder itself has inherited permissions? And, is there any way I can circumvent this behaviour?
